# Do we have a way to know the X Axis value of first point in line chart?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, label, min, linechart

There are multiple series in my line chart. Each series contains multiple points. I wonder is there a property I can easily use to get the min/max X Axis value among all of those points for all series? Or whether the chart doesn't support this I have to get the value from my data set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Data:

Series A:
Argument:Value:
A:1
B:2
C:3

Series B:
Argument:Value:
A:2
B:3
C:4
D:5

You can use the following code to get the min and max value.

```
var dg = (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram;
var minXValue = dg.AxisX.WholeRange.MinValue;
var maxXValue = dg.AxisX.WholeRange.MaxValue;
```

If you want to only get the min and max values for the visible range. use this

```
var dg = (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram;
var minXValue = dg.AxisX.VisualRange.MinValue;
var maxXValue = dg.AxisX.VisualRange.MaxValue;
```

Result base on whole range code above

Min X Value: A
Max X Value: D

Hope this helps